# how to have one common function for sorting in a gridview in c# class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am  developing a  custom  grid  view  control.  with paging, searching, sorting
 now I need to write one  common  function  for  sorting, searching  in different  class file

In  sorting  i am   trying   to use this  function

```
public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }

}
```

but in c# class file we don't have a viewstate  properties. So how can i  solve  this issue?

If I  write   one  function  common for  sorting in a  class file  so that iI can use  in all the pages  of  the  gridview  where    sorting is  required.

Any  help  on this issue  would  be  great.

Thank  you.

Comment: How is it even *possible* to ask 19 questions and not mark a single answer? =)

Comment: Can you imagine the world of hurt this guy is setting himself up for?

Answer (score 1):

If your control inherit from System.Web.UI.Control, you have access to a protected ViewState property.